# How can i make two numbers 9 and 3 as special Number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, special-characters, restriction

I am creating a simple function to check the special character in Python. We make a Python Program to check if a string contains any special character.

```
import re 

def run(string): 
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]') 
    if(regex.search(string) == None): 
        print("String value is accepted")       
    else: 
        print("String value is not accepted.") 

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    # Here in "money@rupay" the @ is a special character.
    string = "money@rupay"
    run(string) 
    # The Output is:- String value is not accepted.
```

In function, I check the special characters `[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]` reject as String.
It works perfectly.

What is the way to pass special numbers as the restricted number in python?
I want to pass some number as a special number in python like- `9` and `3`. How can I make `9 and 3` as a special number which is restricted in the python program?

Comment: add 9 and 3 in the brackets in re.compile()

Comment: it works. But if i have some specials words and I want to make all these words special in python. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `9` and `3` into brackets in your regex pattern:

```py
import re 

def run(string): 
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:93]') 
    if(regex.search(string) == None): 
        print("String value is accepted")       
    else: 
        print("String value is not accepted.")
```

Comment: yes it works. If i want to make some sentences special. how can I do that.

Comment: @RakshaSaini Did you mean a string of characters? For example '93'?

Comment: I think I got the point. Try this: `regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]|word1|word2')` with `word1`, `word2` are special words that you need to restrict.

Comment: I think you need something like this: `(?<![\w\d])MY SPECIAL SENTENCE(?![\w\d])`